# Simple Polymer component doesn't work on Safari 10

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, polymer, web-component

Why this code works on Chrome but not on Safari ? Error : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Polymer

Mac OSX 10.11.6.

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="/node_modules/webcomponents.js/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="/node_modules/Polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <dom-module id="my-test">
    <template>
        Hello !
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <script>
  Polymer({
      is: 'my-test'
    });
  </script>

  <my-test>
  </my-test>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in Chrome `<link rel="import">` is processed synchronously, while in Safari it is first not recognized (because not implemented natively). So `Polymer()` is not defined when it is parsed.

You should wait for the `HTMLImportsLoaded` event before invoking Polymer().

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener( "HTMLImportsLoaded", function () {
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-test'
        });
    })
</script>
```

You can also use instead `HTMLImports.whenReady()` as explained in the [Polymer documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#main-document-definitions).

```
<script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady( function () {
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-test'
        });
    })
</script>
```